# What does "WebSocket upgrade request failed" exception mean in a context of Web sockets?

Tags: wcf, websocket, iis-8

When trying to use WCF with `NetHttpBinding` on IIS 8 Express, the following `WebSocketException` is thrown on client side when the client attempts to connect:

> WebSocket upgrade request failed. Received response status code '200 (OK)', expected: '101 (SwitchingProtocols)'.

[Google Search](https://www.google.com/?q=%22WebSocket%20upgrade%20request%20failed%22) is not helpful.

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: It seems like the server responds to the websocket connection attempt as if it were a normal HTTP request. Make sure that the server is configured properly to treat requests to the URL as websocket.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means the HTTP server does not support WebSockets on that URL.  During a WebSocket negotiation, a standard HTTP 1.1 `GET` request is sent to the server with a special `Upgrade: websocket` header to let the server know that the client wants the connection to use a WebSocket and not HTTP.  If the server supports WebSockets, and the request headers are valid, the server is required to send a `101` reply to let the client know that the server is switching the connection over to a WebSocket for the duration of the connection.  Any other reply other than a 3xx redirect means means the server does not recognize or allow the `Upgrade` request on that URL.