# Rails 6 ActionCable Unable to Upgrade WebSocket Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, actioncable

I have been struggling to get my Rails app deployed correctly for a while now, and have decided it is finally time to consult the community for some help. I have read just about every stackoverflow post on this issues, including the following, with no luck:

- [Rails 5 ActionCable fails to upgrade to WebSocket on Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021338/rails-5-actioncable-fails-to-upgrade-to-websocket-on-elastic-beanstalk) -> From this post I ensured I was using an Application Load Balancer
- [ActionCable on AWS: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536926/actioncable-on-aws-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code) -> Configured an nginx proxy, with no change

### Problem Description

I am using the following setup:

- Ruby 2.7.5
- Rails 6.1.0
- GraphQL
- React Frontend (separate repo)
- Elastic Beanstalk

  - Ruby 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.1
- Application Load Balancer
- Postgres ActionCable adapter

My application is deployed to AWS Elasticbeanstalk and all requests to `/graphql` are successful. However, when attempting to connect to `/cable` I get this error in my browser console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.redacted.io/cable' failed:
```

When checking the Elastic Beanstalk logs I see:
`/var/app/containerfiles/logs/production.log`:

```
I, [2022-02-20T19:35:25.849990 #32761]  INFO -- : [8e1d3e86-81cc-4708-89d3-ebad56470f8f] Started GET "/cable" for <redacted IP> at 2022-02-20 19:35:25 +0000
I, [2022-02-20T19:35:25.850342 #32761]  INFO -- : [8e1d3e86-81cc-4708-89d3-ebad56470f8f] Started GET "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for <redacted IP> at 2022-02-20 19:35:25 +0000
E, [2022-02-20T19:35:25.850384 #32761] ERROR -- : [8e1d3e86-81cc-4708-89d3-ebad56470f8f] Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: close, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
I, [2022-02-20T19:35:25.850419 #32761]  INFO -- : [8e1d3e86-81cc-4708-89d3-ebad56470f8f] Finished "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for <redacted IP> at 2022-02-20 19:35:25 +0000
```

### Potentially Relevant Files

`cable.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: postgresql
```

`production.rb`:

```
...
config.action_cable.url = 'wss://api.redacted.io/cable'

config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['redacted.io', 'http://redacted.io', 'https://redacted.io']
...
```

`.ebextensions/nginx_proxy.config`:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/websockets.conf" :
    content: |
      upstream backend {
          server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
      }

      server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

      server {
          listen 80;

          access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
          error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

          server_name redacted.elasticbeanstalk.com;

          # prevents 502 bad gateway error
          large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

          location / {
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
              proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

              # prevents 502 bad gateway error
              proxy_buffers 8 32k;
              proxy_buffer_size 64k;

              proxy_pass http://backend;
              proxy_redirect off;

              location /assets {
                root /var/app/current/public;
              }

              # enables WS support
              location /cable {
                proxy_pass http://backend/cable;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
              }
          }
      }


container_commands:
  01restart_nginx:
    command: "nginx -t && service nginx restart"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After posting on reddit, I was able to fix my issue by:

1. Removing my `.ebextensions/nginx_proxy.config` file.
2. Creating a new file, `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/websocket.conf` with the contents:

```
location /cable {
  proxy_pass http://my_app/cable;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: For me, to make this working . I have to chang this or server will consider request as non-websocket.
`proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18196586/3551956